# WinRAR "Total path and file name length must not exceed 260 characters"

Tags: winrar

WinRAR is giving me the 260 character limit error on a path/filename that is only 216 characters long. See below. The reason is the extraction destination is a temporary folder that is tool long. See https://superuser.com/questions/154969/where-winrar-extracts-files for details on this folder.

```
!   C:\<path>\<filename.rar>: Cannot create <filename>
Total path and file name length must not exceed 260 characters
```

How do I modify this?

Comment: Suggestion to MODs: If the question belongs on Super User, then please move it to Super User. I have had questions blocked when they are perfectly suited to StackExchange somewhere. This was before I understood StackExchange and I admit I still may not understand it fully as I'm not a seasoned user yet. Blocking and closing (and, worse, down-voting) the valid efforts of newcomers is very unwelcoming behavior, whereas moving the topic at hand helps everyone as well as teach the newcomer how things work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can change Winrar's default temp directory from Winrar's Options > Settings > Paths tab. Thanks to https://superuser.com/questions/154969/where-winrar-extracts-files for the solution.

For the shortest path possible, set it to c:/ or some other driver's root. Pay attention to the temporary folders it will create (and not delete) that starts with "RAR..." or "Rar...". You can delete this once WinRAR is done.

Comment: This doesn't work if you are using a self-extracting archive and do not have WinRAR installed. I am just now running into this and had to extract to C:\a\ to squeak by as C:\ac\ produced the error!